# Script /bin/bash augment too long and grep section not working in find

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, find

I'm trying to write a simple script that will find if a field in a file is blank,e.g 
x_Field=""

```
find /mnt/sdb1/*/*/ -name 'files.txt' -type f -follow -print0 {} \; | xargs -0 grep -o -P '(?<=x_Field).*(?=y_Field)' | cut -c 3 | awk '{sub(/..$/,"")}1'
```

I think the command works without the find but not with the find?

```
grep -o -P '(?<=x_Field).*(?=y_Field)' | cut -c 3 | awk '{sub(/..$/,"")}1'
```

Also when I get this half working if seems I have too many files to scan so it gives a augment too long :-(

Sorry also to add in that I need to go through hundreds of subfolders hence why I used the wildcard

Comment: Try adding `-n1` option to `xargs`..

Comment: The 'argument list too long' is coming from the glob expansion of `find /mnt/sdb1/*/*`.  There's no need for that.  Just do `find /mnt/sdb1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` command has a number of errors.

Apparently, `/mnt/sdb1/*/*` expands to a list which is too long for your shell.  You can replace that with `/mnt/sdb1 -mindepth 2` (assuming you want to avoid finding anything in the directories immediately below `sdb1`).

The `{} \;` would be useful if you had an `-exec` option, but you don't.

Also, the `grep | cut | awk` can probably be refactored into a single Awk script, but without properly understanding what it's supposed to accomplish, it's hard to write a replacement.

Comment: So the output I want to get is "" thats why I've used a cut | grep | awk to trim out all the bits... example of the field contents "x_Field":"test data","y_Field":"Description"

Comment: So simply `grep 'x_Field=""'` then?

Comment: Yep but I ideally only want to put this into a true loop so only show me files where you have context in this field, so out of the 2000 files scanned I just want to know the location of files that use the x_field

Comment: `find /mnt/sdb1 -mindepth 2 -type f -name files.txt -follow -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -l 'x_Field": *""'` will print file names; switch to `-Hon` to print the matches with line numbers.

Comment: Hi, the grep works for files that have the field empty whereas I'm looking to locate files where the field is not empty :-)

Comment: Then `grep -l '"x_Field": *"[^"]'`

Comment: Wicked that works, would I use ! -type d to exclude folder names from the output?

Comment: I'm getting grep: 415: Is a directory   on the output

Comment: Vaguely speculate that this might be related to symlinks; but I cannot easily think of a scenario where that could happen if your command line is correct.

Comment: Thats cool, I think I can do a work on around on this - How would I get the contents on the field? As -Hon only gives me the first letter of the fields contents

Comment: Then use `'"x_Field": *"[^"]*'` or otherwise recraft the regex to capture the part you want (which still isn't quite clear).

Comment: Sorry so the files contain lots of JSON fields and I want to be able to see if the x_Field is being used, so far your commands locate the files perfectly :-) but now I just need to get the context of the x_Field":"This is date",

Comment: You have changed the requirements at least twice. When I showed how to get the value, you said you only want the empty value. If you really cannot figure out how to make minor modifications to the regex going forward, I would suggest accepting this answer and posting new questions when you find new problems.